# A compact subspace of metric space with no isolated points.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

Suppose $X$ is a metric space which is connected and has no isolated points. Then I want to show that it will have some non-empty compact subspace $Y$ such that $Y$ has no isolated points. I don't know if my assertion is correct. If not, please give counterexample. Also, can we find non-empty subspace $Y$ such that $Y$ is both compact and connected.

Comment: Spaces $X$ without such a subspace $Y$ would not only have to fail to be path connected, but would fail to have any non-trivial paths. Their path-connected components would have to be singletons, despite $X$ being connected.

Comment: If $X$ is a $1$-point space then $X$ is a connected metric space, and does not have a nonempty subspace $Y$ with no isolated points.

Comment: A nontrivial counterexample assuming the axiom of choice: Let $X$ be a Bernstein subset of $\mathbb R^2$, i.e., neither $X$ nor $\mathbb R^2\setminus X$ contains an uncountable closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Then $X$ is a connected metric space which noes not have a closed subspace with no isolated points.

Comment: @bof How can we be sure that such set exists.

Comment: It's a straightforward construction by transfinite induction, using the fact that each uncountable closed set contains $2^{\aleph_0}$ points, and the number of closed sets is just $2^{\aleph_0}$. And of course the continuum can be well-ordered, since the axiom of choice is assumed.

Comment: @bof Can such set $X$ be similarly created for $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @bof Did you mean number of uncountable closed sets is just $2^{\mathbb{N_0}}$ in your early statement ?

Comment: @LordKK: We certainly cannot create such an example in $\mathbb{R}$, since a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with at least two points must be an interval (open, closed, or half-open), which in all cases will contain a smaller closed interval.

Comment: The number of uncountable closed sets, the number of closed sets, the number of Borel sets, all equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$. Of course it's the uncountable closed sets that are relevant here. You can also construct a Bernstein subset of $\mathbb R$ but of course it won't be connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $X$ be a [Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) subset of $\mathbb R^2$, i.e., a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ such that both $X$ and $\mathbb R^2\setminus X$ meet every uncountable closed subset of $X$. (Such sets exist, assuming the axiom of choice.) Then $X$ is a connected metric space with no isolated points, and every nonempty compact subspace of $X$ has an isolated point.

**Why is $X$ connected?** Assume for a contradiction that $X=X_1\cup X_2$ where $X_1,X_2$ are nonempty and relatively closed in $X$, and $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$. Taking closures in $\mathbb R^2$ we have $\overline{X_1}\cup\overline{X_2}=\overline X=\mathbb R^2$, and $\overline{X_1}\cap\overline{X_2}$ is disjoint from $X$, whence $\overline{X_1}\cap\overline{X_2}$ is countable. Choose points $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2\in X_2$. Let $\mathcal A$ be an uncountable collection of internally disjoint arcs from $x_1$ to $x_2$. Since $x_1,x_2\notin\overline{X_1}\cap\overline{X_2}$, some arc $A\in\mathcal A$ is disjoint from $\overline{X_1}\cap\overline{X_2}$. But then $A\cap\overline{X_1}$ and $A\cap\overline{X_2}$ are two disjoint nonempty subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$, which is impossible since $A$ is connected.

Comment: Can you explain why X is connected ?